# Associated list of entity. Getting List with null, not with right entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I think, that is trival, but i can't recognize my logic error.

So i have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT"))
@SequenceGenerator(name = "project_seq_generator", allocationSize = 20, 
initialValue = 1, sequenceName = "project_seq")
public class Project implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    /** The cost centres. */
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectid")
    private List<Center> costCentres = new ArrayList<Center>();

    ...

}
```

There are other variables but isn't valuable for this question

The other side - `Center`, doesn't have mapped this.

When i try to get the `costCentres` with getter then i getting a list with `null` values.

Is there anything bad in this mapping?

I can normally add a project, and there is a center in database with associate projectid normally.

Another question is - can i create criteria to get these associated `Center`'s?

How i fetch it:

```
public ProjectDTO getProjectByID(int projectID) {
    Project project = null;
    try {
        project = (Project) session.get(project.class, projectID);
    } catch(HibernateException e) {
        // blabla
    }
    return convertToProjectDTO(project);
}
```

And root:

```
public ProjectDTO getProjectByID(int projectID) throws HibernateException {
    Transaction tx = null; 
    Session session = HibernateUtils.getNewSession();
    ProjectDTO result = null;
    ProjectManager manager = new ProjectManager(session);
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        result = manager.getProjectByID(projectID);
        tx.commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // Bla BLa
    } finally {
        HibernateUtils.conditionalRollback(session);
    }

    return result;
}
```

That was a convertTo problem, not hibernate.

Question is not valid anymore

That was problem with

```
return null;
```

In code of method convertTo
Sorry for my dumb

Comment: How are you fetching `costCentres`? Post some code!

Comment: What sql query is generated by hibernate when you load Center entity?

Comment: Can you include the code for `convertToProjectDTO` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307849/hibernate-returns-list-with-null-values-onetomany-annotation-with-list-type

Comment: I will post code tommorow

Comment: I ran your code and i am getting the mapped child entities `costCentres` as well. Please post your error stack.

Comment: @Naros thanks for tip. That was convertTo problem. 
And i search in the wrong place.

Sorry for my dumb :D have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You get List with nulls because you initialize it in the field declaration without **final** word.

**You have 3 options**

If you need ArrayList initialization do it in the getter:

```
public List<Center> getCostCentres() {
 if (costCentres==null)return new ArrayList<Center>();
    return costCentres;
}
```

Or you can add **final**  word as

```
private final List<Center> costCentres = new ArrayList<Center>();
```

Or init it in the constructor.

Comment: Really, That can be the reason?

Comment: @Razikus could you try it out?

Comment: Not now, cause i quit my place now.

Comment: You answer doesn't seem to be correct. I ran the exact same code and i am getting the desired result. The child entities.